# Binary instance with sum type

Tags: haskell

I am processing a couple of different protocols and storing their messages in a channel. To do this I am using a sum type capturing both types of messages. Now I am having trouble writing a decoding instance for `Binary` - I know which protocol I want to decode, but I don't know how to force it without using ugly newtype wrappers. Code is:

```
    -- Supported protocols
    data ProtoA = ProtoA
    data ProtoB = ProtoB

    -- Protocol sum type for storing messages in a channel.
    data P = PA ProtoA | PB ProtoB

    -- messages stored in a channel that can support either message.
    type PChan = TChan P

    instance Binary ProtoA where
      put ProtoA = return ()
      get = return ProtoA

    instance Binary ProtoB where
      put ProtoB = return ()
      get = return ProtoB

    instance Binary P where
      -- on put, have the constructor available to drive behavior
      put (PA ProtoA) = return ()
      put (PB ProtoB) = return ()
      -- on get, nothing to differentiate behavior
      -- don't want alternation
      get = undefined

    -- Yuck, wrapped newtypes instances...
    newtype PA' = PA' P
    newtype PB' = PB' P

    instance Binary PA' where
      put (PA' (PA ProtoA)) = return ()
      put (PA' (PB ProtoB)) = fail "shouldn't happen"
      get = return (PA' (PA ProtoA))

    instance Binary PB' where
      put (PB' (PA ProtoA)) = fail "shouldn't happen"
      put (PB' (PB ProtoB)) = return ()
      get = return (PB' (PB ProtoB))
```

Is there a better way to handle this? Maybe with phantom types? At the time of decoding, I know which protocol I am dealing with - but not sure how to force it. Advice and/or suggestions very much welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you only have `ProtoA` or `ProtoB` messages, use `get :: Get ProtoA` or `get :: Get ProtoB` to read them. There's no reason to try to read a `P` if you know that it's a `ProtoA`. If you want a `P` holding a `ProtoA` you can use `(PA <$> get) :: Get P`.

You won't read a `P` unless you don't know whether it's a `PA` or a `PB`, so your `Binary P` instance *should* write a tag that you can use to differentiate between `PA`s and `PB`s.

```
instance Binary P where
    put (PA a) = do put (0 :: Word8)
                    put a
    put (PB b) = do put (1 :: Word8)
                    put b
    get = do t <- get :: Get Word8
             case t of
                  0 -> PA <$> get
                  1 -> PB <$> get
```

If you are going to write `P`s to somewhere that should only be `ProtoA`s or `ProtoB`s it's your job to check and make sure that that is true. Then use `put :: ProtoA -> Put` or `put :: ProtoB -> Put`.